# convert javascript comments into .chm files using yuidoc

Tags: javascript, chm, yuidoc

I am using YUIDOC to convert Javascript comments to a chm file.

I have installed node.js
then,I have run the command yuidoc
but when I am running the command `yuidoc E:\foldername\filename.js` then no error is coming but warning come that path argumen is missing and options are also displayed.
Kindly tell me how to do this successfully.
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue is solved.
I have removed the read-only attribute from the folder property.

Answer (score 0):

Use server mode to run yuidoc with node. For example:

```
yuidoc --server
```

Will start a server at the following address:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

Place the JavaScript files in a subfolder of the yuidoc path rather than on a separate drive.

**References**

- [Running YUIDoc on the Command Line](http://yui.github.io/yuidoc/args/index.html#command-line)